# Git Bash: how to change directory when activating virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, git-bash

Created virtualenvs on Python 3.6.1 using virtualenvwrapper, using Git Bash mingw64 terminal, Win7.

How can I have the working directory automatically changed to another location when I activate a specific virtual environment?

Example: When I run `workon temp_env` I want the working directory to be changed to as if I just ran `cd "/c/Users/me/Desktop/temp_env"`.

Comment: Are you using [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io)? I assume so since you mention `workon`. If so, read the docs [here](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html) which mention you can either do `workon -c env_name` or set an environment variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD`

Comment: Yep I'm using virtualenvwrapper. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a setup where the working directory would automatically change to a location defined for a specific virtual environment.

1. After installing `virtualenvwrapper` I added following lines to `~/.bashrc` per the [docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html?highlight=VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD)

   ```
   export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
   source virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```
2. Then I created a new virtual env: `mkvirtualenv temp_env`
3. Inside the `$HOME/.virtualenvs/temp_env` directory, I added a line to the `postactivate` script (which was created with the virtual env) to change working directory

   ```
    cd "/path/to/folder/"
   ```

More info on ways to define behavior when activating, deactivating, etc virtual environments are located [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#postactivate).